# I can't add loop cut

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I'm having a problem where I can't add a loop cut.
Basically, I filled a gap with the merge by distance, and now I can't add a loop cut.

(Sorry for bad english)
[image]

[.blend file](https://filebin.net/zgnuh6dr8fby9mga)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a face on the inside of the mesh. Select and delete it then the loop cut will follow the quad topology nicely.

[image]